# why we get - likely client has closed socket - from zookeeper logs

Tags: linux, apache-zookeeper

we have 3 zookeeper servers ( redhat 7.4 ) that serve many applications

from each of the zookeeper servers logs , we can see many messages as the following:

```
2019-09-12 17:56:00,393 [myid:0] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2131:NIOServerCnxn@368] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x6d396d177c07d4, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:239)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

after searching in google , I found the following solution

*In /bin/zkServer.sh, add a JVMFLAGS environment variable assignment near the top of the script, e.g., to increase the file size limit to 5MiB:*

```
JVMFLAGS="$JVMFLAGS -Djute.maxbuffer=5000000"
```

I not test it , but my feeling this isn't the right direction

so I get lost here